# Creating multiple indexes for table join to accommodate fuzzy matching

Tags: sql, indexing

I'm trying to match user-provided postal address data to an address reference dataset. I want to index both datasets and join on the indexed field. In a perfect world, this would use a key consisting of the full address (e.g., `WHERE REF_ADDR = INPUT_ADDR` will give `100 W Main St, Springfield, OH 45502 = 100 W Main St, Springfield, OH 45502`). Of course, addresses are rarely perfect, so I have a script that can accommodate for differences using fuzzy logic. However because this script is very slow, I want to reduce the number of candidates from the reference dataset to which the matching process is attempted before it is used. To find all potential candidates, I intend to create an indexed key that is derived from individual address components to be used for joining. The problem is, one key alone will not capture all the possible candidates. I would likely need to create multiple indexed keys in order to capture all candidates.

For example, an indexed key in the form of `100 WMNST 455` for address `100 W Main St, Springfield, OH 45502` will be good most of the time, but there can be any number of address errors that will not be caught by such a key. In order to accommodate all potential errors that the matching process will recognize, I would likely need to implement at least several indexed keys for joining.

I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations for handling this issue. The reference dataset consists of 40M records, and the user-provided address data is typically around 10,000 records. Would it be more effective to simply use `LIKE` and `OR` queries on the address fields as opposed to the method I'm proposing? It is not unusual to encounter the following variations within the latter dataset (accommodated for by the script):

```
Address: 100 W MAIN
City: 
Zip: 45502

Address: 100 MAIN ST
City: SPNGFLD
Zip:

Address: 100 W MAIN STREET
City: SPRINGFIELD
Zip: 54502

Address: 100 MAIN
City: NORTHRIDGE
Zip: 45502
```

Comment: How about a separate table which contains a row for each possible match, linking back to the original table's one record. When you query for a match, you query this table with its single index.

Comment: The possible matches will have to come from the reference data though. Are you saying produce a table from the possible matches within the reference data, and then perform the match attempts using this table instead of the reference data that contains the joined user-provided address data? Will that increase performance?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking - so when you insert `123 E Main` into the real table, you'd insert `123 Main`, `123 East Main`, and however many other possibilities exist into your new table - each of those records has a FK against your original record. When you query, you'd query the new table. I don't know for sure that performance would be great, but it would be a simple solution since there's a simple index on a single column, and all of your logic to retrieve possible matches gets done once in advance, rather than on the fly during a `select` query.

Comment: That would make sense. I'll take that into consideration. Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what DB system you are using you must have try to see if any inbuilt functionality can be used. 
For example if you are working on SQL SERVER, options I can think of is “Change Data Capture”, “Full text search”, “Filtered Index”,  etc…..
But regardless of the DB system if you want to develop your own that can be implemented on any DB system then this might interest you.

What you have ask is to suggest some indexing options but to me that is not the right question as you will be limited with very few options as the data grows in the table and/or your search criteria becomes complex. If schema design itself is not scalable then you will not be able to implement more performance improvements later in extreme data cases.

I Created design to implement search so called “Google like Search” in our project whereas user start typing the text appropriate matching text suggestions should come up on result.
Also user can control type of search should be performed by setting.

*By that mean I mean “Exact Match”, "Similar Match", “Start With A”, “Ends With A”, or “Contain A”.*

In your case Address is kind of Data where Exact Match is rarely happens. So i guess you can skip that but if you want to implement that, it can done with some changes. You can customize it as you need depending on the sophistication and complexity you want to handle.
here’s the concept.

We will need 5 tables.

[image: Search Expression Table Explanations]

Now question is How does this schema help or improve your fuzzy search ?

Notice that each table has ONLY 2 Clumns with INTEGER and/OR STRING type, We can have Clustered index on each table that includes both column..

Because we have separated out the data by accuracy you can give option to user how much accurate data user want to access. this will reduce the search load and also batch your search operation.

**If this is something you want to go for then let me know. creating the dummy data and coming up with performance number is not a big deal. I can help out with coming up final design that may work for you.**

[image: Search Expression Table Examples]

Comment: Wow, extremely thorough answer, Anup. I apologize for the late reply. I'll be sure to take all of this into account when it comes time for implementation.