# Position independent string matching

Tags: mysql, solr, sphinx, string-matching

I have 2,000,000 strings in my mysql database. Now , when a new string comes as input, I try to find out if the string is already in my database, else, I insert the string.

**Definition of String Match**

For my case, position of a word in the text doesn't matter. Only all the words should be present in the string and no extra words in either string.

Ex - **Ram is a boy** AND **boy is a Ram** will be said to match. **Ram is a good boy** won't match.

PS - Please ignore the sense

Now, my question is what is the best way to do these matching given the number of strings(2,000,000) I have to match with .

**Solution I could think of :**

1. Index all the strings in SOLR/Sphinx
2. On new search, I will just
   hit the search server and have to consider at max top 10 strings

**Advantages :-**

1. Faster than mysql full text search

**Disadvantages :-**

1. Keeping search server updated with the new queries in mysql
   database.

Are there any other better solutions that I can go for ? Any suggestions and approach to tackle this are most welcome :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just compute a second column that has the words in sorted order. THen just a unique index on that column :)

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD sorted varchar(255) not null, unique index(sorted);
```

then... (PHP for convenience, but other languages will be similar)

```
$words = explode(' ',trim($string));
sort($words);
$sorted = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(' ',$words));
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table SET `string`='$string',`sorted`='$sorted'";
```

Comment: That's an awesome idea :)

Comment: sort words, fold case, remove duplicates

Comment: mysql collations will probably take care of folding case for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create some more tables that stores the information about your existing data.
so that regardless of how much data your table has you will not have to deal with performance issue during "match/check and insert" logic in your query.

please check the schema suggestion I have made for similar requirement in another post on SO.

[accommodate fuzzy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189383/creating-multiple-indexes-for-table-join-to-accommodate-fuzzy-matching/19191941#19191941)

in above post to achieve your needs you will need just one extra table where I have mentioned data match with 90% accuracy. let me know if that answer is not clear or you have any doubt on that.

EDIT-1

in your case you will have 3 tables. one you already have, where you have your 2,000,000 string messages stored. now another two table i was talking about is as follows.
second table to store all unique Expression (unique word accross all messages)
third table to store link between each Expression(word) and messgae that word appears in.
see the below query results.

[image]

[image]

Now lets say your input has a string "Is Boy Ram"
first extract Each Expression from string you have  3 in this string. "Is" and "Ram" and "Boy".
now its just matter of completing the Select query to see if these all expression exist in last table
"MyData_ExpressionString" for single StringID. I guess now you have better picture and you know what to do next. and yes, i haven't created Indexes but I guess you already know what indexes you will need.

Comment: I am not getting your solution in that post. Can you elaborate with some examples related to this case ?

Comment: Updated the response under Edit-1.

Comment: Hey, I think in this method, you will end up mapping Ram boy to Ram is boy etc ? ANyways, Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: No, and that's where the first check come. Your query should account for the only stringID which has exact numbers of expression as your search string has.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a bloom filter for each string by adding all the words to the filter for the given string.  On any new string lookup, calculate the bloom filter, and lookup the matching strings in the DB.

You probably can get by with a fairly short bloom filter, some testing on your strings could tell you how long you need.

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive, please ?